# Functions on the unit disk $f(0)=1$ and $Re f >0$ Prove the given inequality.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A$ denote the set of all holomorphic functions $f(z)$ on the open unit disk $D=\lbrace |z|<1 \rbrace$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $\text{Re }f>0$. Show that if $F \in A$, then it satisifies the inequality

$$\frac{1-|z|}{1+|z|} \leq |f(z)| \leq \frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|} $$

I am not sure how to prove this inequality. I know that the mapping from the unit disk to the right half plane is given by $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$, so I think that is where the upper bound comes from, although I am not sure how to prove that this is the tightest upper bound and I don't know how to get the lower bound.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227575/application-of-schwarz-proposition-to-prove-inequality, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040252/holomorphic-function-inequalities-possibly-using-schwarzs-lemma, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/547565/42969

Comment: I hadn't seen these links! Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with @Martin R. Since your question only involves $\left|f\right|$, it could observe some simplification.

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the unit disk, $\mathbb{H}$ be the right-half plane. Define
\begin{align}
\Phi:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{D},&&z\mapsto\frac{z-1}{z+1}.
\end{align}
Obviously, $\Phi(1)=0$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\Phi\circ f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D},&&0\mapsto 0.
\end{align}
Thanks to this fact, Schwarz lemma applies, i.e.,
$$
\left|\Phi\circ f(z)\right|\le\left|z\right|
$$
holds for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$. The above inequality is exactly
$$
\left|\frac{f(z)-1}{f(z)+1}\right|\le\left|z\right|\iff\left|f(z)-1\right|\le\left|z\right|\left|f(z)+1\right|.
$$
The rest of your task is to play with this last inequality. For one thing,
$$
\left|f\right|-1\le\left|f-1\right|\le\left|z\right|\left|f+1\right|\le\left|z\right|\left(\left|f\right|+1\right),
$$
which yields
$$
\left|f\right|\le\frac{1+\left|z\right|}{1-\left|z\right|}.
$$
For another,
$$
1-\left|f\right|\le\left|f-1\right|\le\left|z\right|\left|f+1\right|\le\left|z\right|\left(\left|f\right|+1\right),
$$
which leads to
$$
\left|f\right|\ge\frac{1-\left|z\right|}{1+\left|z\right|}.
$$
These are exactly what you want.